# PCA zero mean confusion

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm implementing PCA in Matlab and confused about zero mean step. Suppose I have a matrix of dataset X, with each column being an example and each row corresponding to a feature/variable. I think to remove the mean, we should calculate the mean of each row, then subtract it from the values in the same row because we want to remove the mean value of the same variable.

However, from the Stanford websites [here](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:PCA_and_Whitening) and [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Implementing_PCA/Whitening), it seems that it's not true. Instead, they want to remove the mean of each example.
Could you please help me verify this?

Answer (score 2):

For PCA you should definitely subtract the mean of each **feature**, not the mean of each example. This is because the matrix you diagonalize is the 'empirical' covariance matrix, which is defined:

```
E[(X-EX)(X-EX)']
```

where `X` is a vector and `'` is the `transpose` of the matrix. From this formula you see that you subtract something which is sample-independent, since you applied expectation `EX`.

Regarding the links, it is either a mistake, or some implementation-specific or experiment-specific step. It's hard to tell (without reading it thoroughly, which I did not)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding what Stanford are doing.

Your understanding of what you're supposed to do is correct: you calculate the mean of each feature and then subtract that mean from each value within that feature. In your case, take the mean of each row and subtract that mean from each element within the row.

The Stanford example takes an image that it splits into 144 tiles. Each tile corresponds to a 'feature', with 10000 datapoints corresponding to the pixels within the tile. They calculate the mean of each tile/feature and subtract it from each pixel within the tile. The Stanford example may be slightly confusing as it tries to apply feature scaling/PCA to images.

Comment: I am not sure you are right, they explicitly write `for each image patch, compute the mean pixel value and subtract it from that image, this centering the image around zero. You should compute a different mean value for each image patch` - that is, you get a different mean for each example.

Comment: @ItamarKatz Yes, that sentence make me confused